# Add SOAP Header to Volley Request Android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, header, android-volley

i want to add a SOAP Auth Header from ( [.NET web services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4398/Authentication-for-Web-Services-using-SOAP-headers) ) to volley Request in android, i was looking on the Internet but there is not to much information about it. I try this but it's not working:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                // response code
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    //error code
                                }
                        }) 
                        {
                            @Override
                            public Map<String, String> getParams(){
                                return null;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public byte[] getBody(){
                                String temp = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
                                        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n" +
                                        "  <soap:Header>\n" +
                                        "    <AUTHHEADER xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n" +
                                        "      <USERNAME>string</USERNAME>\n" +
                                        "      <PASSWORD>string</PASSWORD>\n" +
                                        "    </AUTHHEADER>\n" +
                                        "  </soap:Header>\n" +
                                        "  <soap:Body>\n" +
                                        "    <SENSITIVEDATA xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" />\n" +
                                        "  </soap:Body>\n" +
                                        "</soap:Envelope>";
                                Log.d("APP", "request String: " + temp);
                                byte[] b = temp.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

                                return b;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public String getBodyContentType()
                            {
                                return "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
                            }
                        };
```

Any idea?? Thank you!.

Comment: To send that body text, you would need to use the PUT method; however, you have specified the GET method in your StringRequest constructor, so it's never sent.

Comment: @krislarson You're right, now i get a response code 500 from the Service, i really don't know if this is the right way for send a SOAP Header in volley or if the header is formed correctly...

Comment: Yeah, now the fun starts.  If you know the server is doing its processing properly, then you can use some HTTP developer tool (e.g. curl) to send data to figure out how to put the request together.  If you have to debug the server too, you'll have to start looking at server logs to figure out why it's choking.

Comment: Hello, did you find out any solution?